# Is there a vba syntax to use within excel vba message boxes to force the user to click OK or have excel close?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting-up an excel spreadsheet and I want to force the user to either accept the terms of service with OK within a message Box or have the program close with Cancel. I am working within visual basic. I also placed the "terms" Macro within the workbook.

Well, I did it the wrong way and locked myself of of my own program.  I keep reworking the code but I can't get it to pull together.

```
Sub terms()

MsgBox Prompt:="By using this program, the user agrees to all Terms and Conditions as set forth herein. Click OK to accept and continue, or cancel to exit program.", Buttons:=vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, Title:="User Agreement:"

Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
If Answer = vbCancel Then Workbooks.Close
If vbOK Then Workbooks.Open
End Sub
```

In the workbook I put the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
terms
End Sub
```

I was expecting the program to close if the user clicked "Cancel" and the program to open if they clicked OK. I tried various different approaches and the latest error noted a compiler error saying argument not optional.

Answer (score 2):

Workbooks is an collection of all Open workbooks. So the statement Workbooks.Open makes no sense, since all members are already open. The open method adds a specific workbook to the collection in the form Workbooks("c:\Test\myspreadsheet.xls").Open  (and logically should have been Add not Open but I see where they were coming from) Similarly Workbooks.Close will close all open workbooks, whereas you would probably only want to close the file just opened.

Also to get a reply from a messagebox you must assign a variable to capture that reply - so

```
    answer = msgbox("You sure?",vbyesno)
```

So what you actually want is

```
Sub terms()
Dim msg as string
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

msg = "By using this program, the user agrees to all Terms and Conditions as set forth herein. Click OK to accept and continue, or cancel to exit program."
Answer = MsgBox(Prompt:=msg, Buttons:=vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, Title:="User Agreement:")


If Answer = vbCancel Then ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your post has me interested in considering a reply to a messagebox and I was struggling on how to structure everything. Would you please demonstrate the syntax. Taking your idea in a different direction, is it possible to insert a link/box to terms and conditions within the messagebox before the user accepts with OK? Thus, the user would have a chance to link to the terms and conditions before committing with either OK or Cancel.

Comment: Think of msgbox as a function that returns the value of the button the user clicked. There's no way of adding a hyperlink to a msgbox, but you could recreate it as a UserForm, and then could add the hyperlink. But them you would have to manage the return value yourself